# Root login in instance with eucalyptus

Tags: eucalyptus

I have a eucalyptus with a node and fronted. I created a instance and i can connect with cloud-user@IpOfIstance. Bu if I get sudo su command, the instance needs a passw of root, but i not created this password. How can I connect in instance with root?  root@ip doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to think that the image you installed isn't properly configured.

Are you able to reproduce the issue with one of the images located at the following URL?

http://emis.eucalyptus.com/

In particular, check out the "Quick start" section to make it more straightforward to install one of the images located there.